# Dajaxice 0.5.1 - Can't seem to make the tutorial work

Tags: ajax, django, dajaxice

I've checked over my stuff repeatedly and I cannot find the issue.
Here's the layout of my project:

- project

  - allthings

    - **init**.py
    - admin.py
    - settings.py
    - models.py
    - views.py
    - tests.py
  - static

    - css
    - dajaxice

      - dajaxice.core.js
    - images
    - js
  - templates

    - testing.html
  - project

    - ajax.py
    - **init**.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py
    - wsgi.py
  - manage.py

### settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL =/static/

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:/Python27/djcode/project/static',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "C:/Python27/djcode/project/templates"
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'allthings',
'dajaxice',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from project.views import hello, testing
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover, dajaxice_config
dajaxice_autodiscover()
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^hello/$', hello),
    ('^testing/$', testing),
    url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover 
dajaxice_autodiscover()

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world!")

def testing(request):
    return render_to_response('testing.html', context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

### ajax.py

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def sayhello(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Hello World'})
```

### testing.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}
<html>
<head><title></title>
{% dajaxice_js_import %}
<script>
function my_callback(data){
    alert(data.message);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    This is to test stuff
    <input type="button" onclick="Dajaxice.project.sayhello(my_callback)" value="Get Message from Server"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

All it does it make a button that puts out an alert.  It should be incredibly simple and yet I get nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'll be honest, I found dajaxice confusing. Tastypie seems to have more traction these days (but it doesn't have its own client lib - but maybe you don't need that these days).

Comment: I've never worked with tastypie but a quick google search shows me that it's quite a bit more complicated.  I would rather write my own serializer and do everything with jquery if Dajaxice and Dajax don't work.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: (I know its not an answer, but i cant comment) ¿ Can you check (using firebug or similar) your AJAX requests ? ¿ Its working AJAX calls ? ¿ What contains the script dajaxice.core.js in the browser ? ¿ They have your sayhello mapped?

Answer (score 1):

Because `dajaxice.core.js` is a non-static template file, `DajaxFinder` will find it and 'render' to a temp folder as a static file.

So your `STATICFILES_DIRS` settings should not contain the file path to `dajaxice.core.js` otherwise the file will be found by `FileSystemFinder` rather than `DajaxFinder`.

You can run `findstatic` to check it is found correctly or not:

```
manage.py findstatic dajaxice\dajaxice.core.js
```

or maybe:

```
manage.py findstatic dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js
```

The output result should be in some temp folder (depending on your OS) and should not be in any folder of your app.

Comment: I have the same problem as described. I actually did what you said, and indeed I get a result in a temp folder. However, I don't have a STATICFILES_DIRS var.